# Why is TCP connection being refused in stm32(STM32H767) using LwIP

Tags: c, networking, tcp, stm32, lwip

Here is my code below

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
err_t tcp_echoserver_accept(void *arg, struct tcp_pcb *newpcb, err_t err);
err_t recv_callback(void *arg, struct tcp_pcb *tpcb, struct pbuf *p, err_t err);
/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
extern struct netif gnetif;
struct tcp_pcb* tcp_pcb;
struct tcp_pcb* tcp_newpcb;
ip_addr_t myIPADDR,destip;
```

```
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_LWIP_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */


  IP_ADDR4(&myIPADDR,192,168,33,1);
  IP_ADDR4(&destip,192,168,33,101);

  tcp_pcb = tcp_new();

  err_t err = tcp_bind(tcp_pcb, &myIPADDR, 8);

  if(err == ERR_OK)
    {
      tcp_pcb = tcp_listen(tcp_pcb);

      tcp_accept(tcp_pcb, tcp_echoserver_accept);

    }

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      ethernetif_input(&gnetif);
      sys_check_timeouts();

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

```
err_t tcp_echoserver_accept(void *arg, struct tcp_pcb *newpcb, err_t err)
{
    tcp_newpcb->state = ESTABLISHED;

    tcp_arg(newpcb, tcp_newpcb);
    tcp_recv(newpcb, recv_callback);

}

err_t recv_callback(void *arg, struct tcp_pcb *tpcb, struct pbuf *p, err_t err)
{
    while(1)
        {
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, LD1_Pin);
            HAL_Delay(500);
        }

return ERR_OK;
}
```

The thing is, when I flash the code and create a tcp connection using an Application, it does the three way handshake successfully, but as soon as the three way handshake is done the board returns a packet with RST, ACK flag set closing the connection entirely.

something like this:-

```
6021    2919.149663 192.168.33.101  192.168.33.1    TCP 66  65222 → 8 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM

6022    2919.150751 192.168.33.1    192.168.33.101  TCP 60  8 → 65222 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=2144 Len=0 MSS=536

6023    2919.150997 192.168.33.101  192.168.33.1    TCP 54  65222 → 8 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65392 Len=0

6024    2919.151743 192.168.33.1    192.168.33.101  TCP 60  8 → 65222 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=24584 Len=0
```

I put an infinite while loop in `recv_callback()` to see if the control ever enters the block, but the LED blinking never happens, that means the control never enters the `recv_callback()`, but the `tcp_echoserver_accept()` runs fine, because I have checked with a similar while loop.

Can someone tell where am i going wrong and how to capture and store the data from incoming tcp packets in the board.

Comment: 'Connection refused' means nothing was listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to.

Comment: @user207421. Thank you for the reply. But I did use tcp_recv() function to receive incoming data, why does it not work?